# Examination System: How to count score from different table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, xampp

```
Private Sub QuestionNavigation()
        rdbA.Checked = False
        rdbB.Checked = False
        rdbC.Checked = False
        rdbD.Checked = False

        Dim qDT As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblQuestions", "")

        numItems = qDT.Rows.Count
        If (numItems > 0) Then
            If (n < numItems) Then
                lblQuestionNumber.Text = "Question {" & (n + 1) & "} of {" & qDT.Rows.Count & "}"
                Qid = qDT.Rows(n).Item(0).ToString()
                txtQuestion.Text = qDT.Rows(n).Item(1).ToString()

                Dim qcDT As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblChoices", " WHERE QuestionID='" & Qid & "'")
                txtChoiceA.Text = qcDT.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString()
                txtChoiceB.Text = qcDT.Rows(1).Item(2).ToString()
                txtChoiceC.Text = qcDT.Rows(2).Item(2).ToString()
                txtChoiceD.Text = qcDT.Rows(3).Item(2).ToString()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You have completed the exam. Thank you for your cooperation.", "Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                Close()
                DisplayForm(frmLogin, frmMain.pnlMain)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is the code on generating the questions from database to the data grid view with round button on it. I already have the table that contains the correct answer but I don't know how will I connect it into the table examinee"s answer and the score will count.

```
Dim Score As String
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

  Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
            If (answerChoice() <> "") Then
                Try
                    RecordRow("INSERT INTO tblExamineeAnswers(ExamineeID, QuestionID, ExamineeAnswer) VALUES ('" & examineeID & "', '" & Qid & "', '" & (Qid & answerChoice()) & "')")
                    n += 1
                    QuestionNavigation()


   Dim dt As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblExamineeAnswers", "")
                For examineeID = 170001 To 170004
                    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                        If examineeID = CInt(row(0)) And row(2).ToString.EndsWith("A") Then
                            Score += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                    dict.Add(examineeID, Score)
                    Score = 0
                Next


                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Your Answer", "Answer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            End If
        End Sub
```

This is the code for pressing the submit button and proceeding unto the next question. And how will I sum all the counted score and put into another table.

tblpersonalinfo

```
ID  LastName    FirstName   Gender  Address ContactNo   EmailAd Score   Name
170001  Padilla John David  Male    Palina East 639304536   dsd 0    
170002  hgdfd   fdgffd  Female  aa  11  1   0    
170003  Laguit  Mark Angelo Male    Pozzorubio  12314   jkwej   0
```

The score attribute is where I am planning to put the score that will be summed.

tblexamineeanswers

```
ExamineeID  QuestionID  ExamineeAnswer
170001  Q170001 Q170001A
170001  Q170002 Q170002A
170001  Q170003 Q170003B
170001  Q170004 Q170004B
170002  Q170001 Q170001C
170002  Q170002 Q170002B
170002  Q170003 Q170003B
170002  Q170004 Q170004C
170003  Q170001 Q170001A
170003  Q170002 Q170002B
170003  Q170003 Q170003B
170003  Q170004 Q170004B
```

This is the table for what did the examinee answered. The letter on the ExamineeAnswer indicates what round button he clicked.

tblchoices

```
 QuestionID ChoiceID    Choice
    Q170001 Q170001A    Paragraph
    Q170001 Q170001B    Sentence
    Q170001 Q170001C    Word
    Q170001 Q170001D    Topic
    Q170002 Q170002A    Masking
    Q170002 Q170002B    Remembering
    Q170002 Q170002C    Hearing
    Q170002 Q170002D    Listening
    Q170003 Q170003A    Airport
    Q170003 Q170003B    Canteen
    Q170003 Q170003C    Garden
    Q170003 Q170003D    School
    Q170004 Q170004A    Common
    Q170004 Q170004B    Communicare
    Q170004 Q170004C    Communar
```

This table shows the choices on the question.

tblquestions

```
QuestionID  Question    
Q170001 A _________ is a group of sentence about one topic...   
Q170002 It is a natural process of recieving aural and vis...   
Q170003 A specific place to show where the departure and a...   
Q170004 The term communication was derived from the term _...
```

this tables shows the question with it's ID

tblanswer

```
QuestionID  ChoiceID
Q170001 Q170001A
Q170002 Q170002A
Q170003 Q170003A
Q170004 Q170004A
```

This table shows what is the correct choice/answer on the specific question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, stop using "PLEASE I NEED THIS UNTIL TOMMOROW", read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking

Comment: @kentLoves read from the link provided by Soumesh

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean to say that.  I'm still new here, I'm sorry

Comment: Did you design the database? I would need a clear idea of the schema.

Comment: @Mary I just edited the post with the database about it, you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

'Pseudo code Dim dt as DataTable - your tblexamineeanswers

```
    Dim Score As Integer
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)
    For ExamineeID = 170001 To 170004
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            If ExamineeID = CInt(row(0)) And row(2).ToString.EndsWith("A") Then
                Score += 1
            End If
        Next
        dict.Add(ExamineeID, Score)
        Score = 0
    Next
```

Now you have a dictionary of the ExamineeId as the key and the total score as value
To view results Add the following below the For...Next

```
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In dict
     Debug.Print($"ExamineeId = {item.Key}, Score = {item.Value}")
Next
```

The data will be in the Immediate window. Find this on the debug menu under Window.

Comment: The ExamineeID will increase automatically whenever someone has to signup and take the exam. How is that? Is it possible when the examinee pressed the Submit Button, the score will already count if the answer is correct

Comment: corrected the score, forgot to zero it out after each examinee

Comment: I cant Dim dt as DataTable properly, can you teach me how to call it?

Comment: I rather assumed you already had a DataTable in your DataSet that matched your tblexamineeanswers. You can roll your own but that seems silly. In your code you show  Dim qDT As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblQuestions", "") Do it this way if this is working only select from tblexamineeanswers

Comment: Okay, so I did put Dim dt As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblExamineeAnswers", "") but whenever I put the code you sent on Private Sub btnSubmit_Click below the QuestionNavigation(), the examineeID says that 'For' loop control variable cannot be of type 'String' because the type does not support the required operators.

Comment: I've edited my post to show If I did something wrong or where am I lacking and if the score counts? how can I insert it into the database tblPersonalInfo on Score attribute

Comment: Are you successfully counting the score? If so, ask a new question about how to update a table. Do research and show what you have tried. New subject, new question.

Comment: not yet, I think i lack on something.       Dim dt As DataTable = DTTable("SELECT *", "tblExamineeAnswers", "")
               
               `For MyexamineeID = 170001 To 170018
                    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                        If examineeID = CInt(row(0)) And row(2).ToString.EndsWith("A") Then
                            Score += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                    dict.Add(MyexamineeID, Score)
                    Score = 0
                Next` will it affect the code when examineeID suddenly increases?

Comment: Whenever I take the exam and answered few questions, it says "The item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: Keys in a dictionary must be unique. If you are retaking the exam under the same ExamineeId then an error will ensue.

Comment: No, one ExamineeID can only exam once. whenever someone signup,  another unique ID is created to take the exam.

Comment: You need to step through the code and debug. The for loops should be running after the exam.

Comment: yeah thanks! I tried to put the `Dim Score` at the top and the `Dim dict` is together with them. Now there's no error occured. how can I know if it is already counting score?

Comment: See my edit to my answer above. Please mark my answer as answer if it has helped you.

Comment: I tried to add the new code below the code you first sent and took a exam, but when I checked on immediate window it is sill blank.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line and examine variables.

Comment: move your cursor to the far left of the code window to the gray line. Click and a red dot will appear. This is a break point.

Comment: Mary, is there anyway I can contact and chat with you actively like facebook if ever you are willing to help me with my system.